# deploying Facebook messenger chatBot with python gnewsclient at line 70 and 136 error

Tags: python, facebook, flask

I have been deploying Facebook messenger chatBot I followed all steps even installing python libary gnewsclient when is about to use some foction of gnewsclient like client.get_news  I got this :

> > > news= client.get_news()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/zila/facebook/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnewsclient/gnewsclient.py", line 70, in get_news
> > >           articles = self.scrape_feed(soup)
> > >         File "/home/zila/facebook/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnewsclient/gnewsclient.py", line 136, in scrape_feed
> > >           article['link'] = entry.link['href'].split('&url=')[1]
> > >       IndexError: list index out of range

can some one try to help me please , i don't have any i dea of this matters

Comment: you have no value here `scrape_feed article['link'] = entry.link['href'].split('&url=')[1] ` and hence the error

Comment: thank you let's see what it's bring

Comment: so what does it brought?